# MySQL ERROR 1064 (42000) importing OpenGeoDB

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, data-import

I want to import the [OpenGeoDB](http://opengeodb.org/wiki/OpenGeoDB) into a database on my Debian VM with MySQL `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.17`:

```
$ mysql -uroot -p -h localhost geodb < opengeodb-begin.sql
```

It fails with the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 14: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8' at line 6
```

The MySQL code around the line 6 in the opengeodb-begin.sql from the [OpenGeoDB download area](http://fa-technik.adfc.de/Codierung/opengeodb/) looks like:

```
/*
 * MySQL
 */



SET NAMES 'utf8';

BEGIN;
/*
 * Table structure for table 'geodb_type_names'
 */

create table geodb_type_names (
  type_id              integer not null,
  type_locale          varchar(5) not null,
  name                 varchar(255) not null,             /* varchar(500)? */
unique (type_id, type_locale)
) TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

So, the DB server seems to have a problem with `TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;`.

At the same time it works on my remote Ubuntu server with MySQL `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41`.

The only significant difference I see is the MySQL version.

What can cause the error?

Answer (score 3):

OK, it seems really to be so, that the problem is the database server version. The keyword `TYPE` is not supported anymore and was replaced with `ENGINE`.

I replaced all `TYPE=...` with `ENGINE=...` in `CREATE` statements like

```
create table geodb_type_names (
  type_id              integer not null,
  type_locale          varchar(5) not null,
  name                 varchar(255) not null,             /* varchar(500)? */
unique (type_id, type_locale)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Now it works.